# Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 / Remove-AppxPackage skip dependencies?

Tags: optimization, uwp

On our CI we continuously build UWP software which we also have to install on the CI clients to execute some smoke or UI tests.
Now in the process of speeding things up I noticed that some portion of time is essentially wasted by installing / uninstalling dependencies, e.g.

```
...\x86\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2.appx
...\x86\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.2.appx
...\x86\Microsoft.VCLibs.x86.Debug.14.00.appx
...\x64\Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2.appx
...\x64\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.2.2.appx
...\x64\Microsoft.VCLibs.x64.Debug.14.00.appx
```

(don't mind debug, it's a test). What is unwelcome here is that we never deploy x86 but spent time on installing dependencies for it.

I am looking therefore for a way to skip the uninstall of the dependencies on our CI to speed at least this part up (which would also mitigate the installation of the unused x86 dependencies).

For some yet undiagnosed reason installing a dev packages takes about 30 seconds and doing this for 10 apps one by one slows things down.

My questions are

1. Why does my configuration install x86 when I only package x64?
   [image: x86]
2. Does somebody know how to avoid uninstalling *implicit* dependencies for an app in order to avoid installing them over and over?
3. Any further hints on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By our testing, we packaged the app into app bundle and then we deleted the dependencies in the dependencies folder under package folder. After that, we installed the app, it will prompt a message showing we need to install those dependencies. So we installed the dependencies manually and installed the app again, it worked this time. At last we uninstall the app and tried to re-install it, it also worked well. So you can also try this way-manually install the dependencies to avoid installing dependencies over and over.

Comment: Nice, will try this and mark as an answer if it helps. Thank you. Did you have experience with running multiple AddDevPackage scripts in parallel to speed up installation?

Comment: By testing, when tried to run the multiple Add-AppDevPackage, it started to install the next package after finishing installing the previous one, so it cannot run in parallel.